# Couchbase Java SDK: Query fails on open bucket

Tags: java, networking, couchbase

I am initiating a Couchbase client in Java and based on the logs, it seems like the client can be successfully created.

```
2023-04-22T15:44:28.624000+0200 [INFO]  com.couchbase.client.core.node.Node [cb-io-1-3] Connected to Node foo   
2023-04-22T15:44:28.674000+0200 [INFO]  com.couchbase.client.core.node.Node [cb-io-1-3] Disconnected from Node foo
2023-04-22T15:44:28.731000+0200 [INFO]  com.couchbase.client.core.config.ConfigurationProvider  [cb-computations-3] Selected network configuration: default 
2023-04-22T15:44:28.753000+0200 [INFO]  com.couchbase.client.core.config.ConfigurationProvider  [cb-computations-3] Opened bucket bucket-name
```

When I am trying to query the bucket though I am getting connection timeout exceptions

```
2023-04-22T15:45:43.738000+0200 [WARN]  com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.Endpoint [cb-io-1-4] [10.10.7.100:11210][KeyValueEndpoint]: Could not connect to remote socket: Operation timed out: /xxx:11210  
2023-04-22T15:45:43.741000+0200 [WARN]  com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.Endpoint [cb-io-1-6] [10.10.7.114:11210][KeyValueEndpoint]: Could not connect to remote socket: Operation timed out: /xxx:11210
```

I have already tried to increasing the timeout of the client to minutes but this just delays the production of the message? What could cause a successful bucket open but a failed query here?

//EDIT

I tried to use the CB provided SDK doctor but I am not sure how helpful this is. The SDK doctor cannot even connect to the specified DNS

```
[ERRO] Failed to fetch configuration via cccp from `cb-dns:11207` (error: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake)
[ERRO] Failed to fetch terse configuration via http from `cb-dns:18091` (error: Get "http://cb-dns:18091/pools/default/b/bucket-name": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers))
[ERRO] All endpoints specified by your connection string were unreachable, further cluster diagnostics are not possible
```

Comment: In my experience, this is often (not always, but very often) a networking issue. You can try using SDK Doctor to help diagnose / confirm - https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/sdk/sdk-doctor.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue. Someone might have the same setup as I do and might benefit from this answer. So I am using a 20 node Couchbase cluster which is sitting behind a AWS ELB. In order for the couchbase client to open the bucket, talking to the ELB was enough since the security groups were configured in a way that the ELB was accessible. Querying though is a different story since the client was trying to connect to the nodes of the cluster themselves. The `ConnectionTimeout` was produced because the security groups configured for the nodes of the cluster did not allow access to me CLI. Once I added the corresponding security group rules, the connection was successful and I could query the cluster.